# SQL - change the number of where clause values depending on number of values passed in

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I have joined 2 tables and trying to delete the rows based on the order.id

```
DELETE order_attachment
FROM order
LEFT OUTER JOIN order_attachment
ON order.id=order_attachment.id
WHERE order.id = ?
```

Now the problem is number of order.id can be 1, 2, or 3 and they come in as an array.
(Ex. [12311] or [12323, 45612] or [23413, 55675, 32512])

I want to delete all the rows in order_attachment table with the order.id with a single transaction.

Questions

1. How can I delete all the rows with a single transaction?
2. How can I change the number of `?` based on orderId array length?
   (1 question mark if length is 1, 2 if length is 2, and 3 if length is 3)

Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused you say the file extension is js so are you putting this query together as a string in JS?

Comment: Yeah, it's in a different module and importing it in the actual api call to DB. I'll just delete it. I think its making it more confused

Comment: so couldn't you when you put your query string together loop through your array and change the where clause to where order id in (x,y,z)?

Comment: I'm not fully understanding what you want to do tbh. What error messages are you getting on your tries?

Comment: In my sql where clause condition, I need to use 1 question mark if there is only 1 orderId and 2 questions marks if there are 2 orderIds. Each request has different length of array and I need to change the number of question marks

Comment: @BryanDellinger in that case query won't be executed if there is only 1 argument. I need the parameterized query to be dynamic so that it can handle different number of arguments.

Comment: I can definitely help you, just gotta find out what exactly you want. What Sql are you using..? MSSQL?

Comment: select len(@string) - len(replace(@string, ',', ''))+1 <- This is a way in MsSQL to count the occurance of , inside of a string. And then you add 1 for the correct number of values within the array(Not really an array, but still.)

Comment: @Stoff I'm using mySQL

Comment: Same thing should be possible in MySQL, but with different syntax. For the values themselves, if you make sure they're always the same lenght, you can do like '%xxxxx%'. If not, you can do a lot of other stuff. cursor can be used aswell.

Comment: Gotcha. So basically stringify it and then pass in. I think I'm getting closer to the answer. Appreciate it.